# Display many reports in one view by ViewBag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, reporting-services

I want to display a lot of reports in one View, but only one show to me in every div.
I have following controller code:

```
ReportViewer rptViewer1 = new ReportViewer();

rptViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
rptViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
rptViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;

rptViewer1.AsyncRendering = true;

rptViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("MyServerAddress");
rptViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "MyPath";

rptViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials("MyCredentials");

ViewBag.ReportViewer1 = rptViewer1;

ReportViewer rptViewer = new ReportViewer();

rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
rptViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
rptViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;

rptViewer.AsyncRendering = true;

rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("MyServerAddress2");
rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "MyPath2";

rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials("MyCredentials");

ViewBag.ReportViewer = rptViewer;
return View();
```

And the View code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { frameborder = "0", width = "500", height = "500", style = "overflow:hidden;", scrolling = "no" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer1 as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { frameborder = "0", width = "500", height = "500", style = "overflow:hidden;", scrolling = "no" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { frameborder = "0", width = "500", height = "500", style = "overflow:hidden;", scrolling = "no" })
</div>
```

When I run page i have

> 3 THE SAME

reports in one row. I do not know where is the problem and why I cannot display 2 unique reports. I do not see where its crush because it compile without problems. 2 addresses to reports are valid and I can show one of them every time.

Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It show same reports because when **DOM load completely** it get only **last reportviewer** in consideration, i have also same problem in one of my code, then i have try as below, please look it may be help you.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.Partial("DisplayClassesListFilter", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "GridId", "classList1" }, { "GridParentDivId", "divClassList1" } })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 classlist1 m-bottom25">
            @Html.Partial("_ClassListWithoutPaging", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "DisplayClasses", true }, { "Controller", "DisplayClasses" }, { "Action", "GetAllClassWithoutPaging" }, { "SearchFunctionName", "BuildSearchCriteriaDisplayClasses1" }, { "GridId", "classList1" }, { "GridParentDivId", "divClassList1" } })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.Partial("DisplayClassesListFilter", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "GridId", "classList2" }, { "GridParentDivId", "divClassList2" } })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 classlist2 m-bottom25">
            @Html.Partial("_ClassListWithoutPaging", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "DisplayClasses", true }, { "Controller", "DisplayClasses" }, { "Action", "GetAllClassWithoutPaging" }, { "SearchFunctionName", "BuildSearchCriteriaDisplayClasses2" }, { "GridId", "classList2" }, { "GridParentDivId", "divClassList2" } })
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where I can pin to your solution a ReportViewer?

Comment: In view code and you have to make decision based on passed ViewDataDictionary in report viewer

Comment: Can You show me example how to pin it in code below?

Comment: Is it possible to give id of report viewer? if so specify that id in view data dictionary and take decision based on that parameter in your code